# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException (Android 7.0)

Tags: android

I'm facing with this crash on Android 7.0:

```
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native Method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:628)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped (ActivityManagerNative.java:4149)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run (ActivityThread.java:4148)
```

I've checked:

- all Intents with Bundle
- all Intents with Service

There is no case in my App, greater than 1Mo.

Have you got some explanations guys? Thank you very much!

Comment: "There is no case in my App, greater than 1Mo" -- is there anything that gets close (since the 1MB limit is for all simultaneous binder transactions)? Does this crash happen consistently? What triggers the crash?

Comment: can you check any aidl if you have?